# Creating a server using QuickServer

Tags: java, sockets

I am following this tutorial:

https://code.google.com/p/quickserver/wiki/QuickStartTutor

but when I execute `java -jar QuickServer.jar -load HelloWorld.xml`

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/PoolableObjectFactory    at
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  at
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)  at
java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)     at
java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)  at
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)  at
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory   at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   ... 6 more
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception exactly says your problem: that class cannot be found on the application classpath, hence the `ClassNotFoundException`.

You need to put all the dependent jars onto the application classpath. In this exact exception, the `commons-pool.jar` Apache library is missing.

The [developers guide](https://code.google.com/p/quickserver/wiki/DevelopersGuideCh2) states, that the Digester and Pool Jakarta Commons Components are dependencies of QuickServer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are executing this from a folder that does not also have the supporting jars. Ie, the following files must be in the same folder as QuickServer.jar as well:

- commons-digester.jar
- commons-collections.jar
- commons-beanutils.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- commons-pool.jar